# How do I use align-items: stretch; in Flexbox when one of my items needs to be a set width?

Tags: css, flexbox

My goal is to have a single line of flex items stretch to fill out the remaining space of a container. The one caveat is that the first item in the container must remain a set width.

Here is a codepen to show you what I mean: http://codepen.io/jimmykup/full/zGVdem/

I'm using `align-items:stretch` to get all of the pink squares to fill out the remainder of its 1000px container and have the same distance between their text values. You'll notice that my fixed width container in red is set to be 400px wide but it's not having that effect.

FYI, I'm testing this in the latest Chrome. Just a heads up as my codepen may not have all of the vendor prefixes applied yet.

**EDIT:** I've had some success with nesting the flex-boxes. Doing a flex-box within a flex-box seems to get me the results I was looking for: http://codepen.io/jimmykup/pen/NqZaGa But I'd really prefer it if I didn't have to add extra HTML and CSS to achieve this affect. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You mean the first item is shrinking when screen size is lower?

Comment: That is what I mean, yes. Although my codepen right now isn't setting the width to 400px at all, regardless of screen size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`flex-basis`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-basis) sets the initial [main size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size) of the [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item), before free space is distributed according to the flex factors.

And since you are using a column layout, the main size is the `height`, not the `width`.

So better use a row layout instead. And then, to distribute the remaining space left in the flex container among the pink flex items, set their [`flex-grow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-grow) factor to a positive value.

```css
.flex-container {
  flex-flow: row nowrap; /* Row layout (default value) */
}
.flex-item {
  flex-grow: 1; /* Distribute remaining space equally */
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.stretch li {
  background: hotpink;
}
.flex-item {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .75em;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.stretch .set-width {
  flex: 0 0 400px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container stretch">
  <li class="set-width flex-item">Set Width (400px)</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Large Text Item</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Very Large Text Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: An answer so good I wish I could accept it twice. Thank you sir!